# How to set parent members when creating inherited struct in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I have a struct type `A`, which I could instantiate with `A(p_a1, p_a2)` and a struct type `B`, which inherits from `A`, that I can instantiate with `B(p_b1, p_b2, p_b3)`.

Is there a standard way to create a `B` instance while also setting `p_a1` and `p_a2`? Would I just set them after creating the `B` instance with `b.p_a1 = v_a1; b.p_a2 = v_a2`?

(Sorry for any incorrect use of terminology. I don't have much experience with C++.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you intend to do is achievable using initialization lists and can be done as follows:

```
struct A
{
    A(int _a):a(_a){}
};

    struct B : public A
    {
        B(int _a, int _b):A(a), b(_b){}
    } ;
```

In the sample code which you have provided, what you are doing in these lines `b.p_a1 = v_a1; b.p_a2 = v_a2` is called assignment. While the former will invoke just the right constructor, latter would invoke the default constructor.

Comment: So, I don't actually have control over the implementation of these structs. I just know that `A` and `B` exist, and `B` inherits from `A`. I'd like to create an instance of `B`, but additionally set members of `A`.

Comment: precisely, you have to explicitly pass the parameters to A's constructor in case you do not want to use A's default constructor

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a C++ feature named constructor initialization lists. This example should clarify it to you:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
        public:
        Foo( int x ) 
        {
                std::cout << "Foo's constructor " 
                          << "called with " 
                          << x 
                          << std::endl; 
        }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
        public:
        Bar(int x, int y, int z) : Foo( x )  // construct the Foo part of Bar
        { 
                std::cout << "Bar's constructor" << std::endl; 
        }
};

int main()
{
        Bar stool(10,11,12);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yasser, though I'm wondering specifically about inheritance for structs. Does this happen in the same way?

Comment: Pretty much, the one c++ difference between structs and classes that i know of is that in struct if you dont explicitly declare members to be private, then they are public.  In classes, if you dont explicitly declare them to be public, they are private.  Other than that difference, classes and structs are the same as far as c++ is concerned.

Comment: Yes, classes and structs are precisely the same except for the default access level.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
struct A { 
  int _a1; 
  int _a2; 
  A(int a1, int a2); //assume it is defined
};

struct B : public A {
  int _b1;
  B(int p1, int p2, int p3);
};

B(int p1, int p2, int p3)
: A(p1,p1), // <<== This is where parent member variables will be initialized. 
  _b1(p3) //or some other way to populate _b1
{ }
```

google "C++ constructor initialization list"